# Why are Inbox messages being moved into Trash in Thunderbird?

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird, email-filter

I have turned OFF all message filter instructions, yet even after restarts, Thunderbird is moving messages to 'Trash'. This has been happening for a week or so.

Ref:  Thunderbird 60.3.1  32 bit on my 64 bit Windows 7 Pro, all up to date.

What I do:

Viewing Inbox, I down-arrow to the next message, which 20% of the time is auto-trashed and the subsequent message is revealed.

I do `Edit / Undo`  ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> should also work) and then Thunderbird retrieves the trashed message.

This is bizarre and a thing I can't explain.

Comment: Junk mail filtering?

Answer (score 1):

When you say you turned off all message filtering, you may not have turned off what's moving your messages.

There are different filters that are controlled in different places:

- **Filters**; these are controlled through `tools | message filters`, and may include both filters provided by Mozilla, like SpamAssassin, and rules you create yourself.
- **Junk Mail Filtering**; with general options accessed through `Edit | Preferences | Security | Junk`.
- **Junk Mail filtering** is turned on and off at the account level, accessed through `Edit | Account Settings` then within each account `Junk Settings`.

The junk mail filtering is a learning system, but it comes with some rudimentary rules built in as a start, and is turned on by default.

If you verify that all filtering is actually disabled, there are many other things that can cause this kind of symptom.  There is a whole Mozilla Knowledge Base article on [disappearing mail](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Disappearing_mail).  Not all of the possibilities listed match your symptoms, but some of the possibilities include:

- corrupted index files (in your case, that would be a good bet, but there are other possibilities)
- anti-virus software deleting messages
- incoming messages sent with incorrect date
- messages read with a different email client

The solutions depend on the cause, and they're covered in that knowledge base article.